# Only activate error eventlistener for specific requested object

Tags: javascript

I try to load a Youtube thumbnail from an URL. If the image from the URL does not exists and so on, a placeholder should be shown.

I tried to achieve this with following `JavaScript` code:

```
const yt = document.getElementById('YoutubeThumbnail'); //img tag of my requested image

yt.addEventListener("error", (){
    yt.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder');
});
```

This works so far but the problem is that sometimes the favicon from my requested site also throws an error. By the way `maxresdefault.jpg` is the image I need.

[image: ![Network tab requested ressources]

Because I'm checking for all errors my code also places the placeholder image when the favicon throws an error and my requested image not.

Is there a possibility to only check my `maxresdefault.jpg` for errors and ignore the favicon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your anonymous error event handler, and check what value is stored in the `src` attribute of the target element.

```
yt.addEventListener("error", (ev){
    if(ev.target.src === 'maxresdefault.jpg') {
        yt.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target.src` and `includes` function such as:

```
const yt = document.getElementById('YoutubeThumbnail'); //img tag of my requested image

yt.addEventListener("error", (event){
    if(event.src.target.includes('maxresdefault.jpg'))
        yt.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder');
});
```